# Exclude Page from being tracked in Omniture

Tags: analytics, adobe-analytics

Is there a way to remove single page from being tracked in Omniture(Site Catalyst). I want to track all pages instead of only one page. I don't want to send request to Omniture if that page has been hit.

Is there a way to update script for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. If you click the cog next to the `Adobe Analytics Tool` on the Overview page in DTM you'll be taken to a settings page. The tab on the bottom titled `Customize Page Code`, this will run before your adobe beacon would normally be sent. Simply put your logic to select the correct page and then return false and your tracking beacon wont fire.

```
if (location.pathname =='whatever') {
    return false;
}
```

**If you don't have any idea what you're doing codewise, be careful. There is a lot of breakage and data loss that can occur if users put bad code here.

If you're unfamiliar with javascript, I would suggest seeking out a little help. If you want to give it a shot but you're unsure of your code, I would suggest navigating to the page that you want to remove, opening the console (F12), and typing `location.pathname`. This will give you the exact string to test again so your code should be:

```
if (location.pathname == 'whatever/string/the/location/pathname/gave/you') {
    return false;
}
```

Make sure you don't forget the quotes. Good luck!